# HQL Join with three tables

Tags: java, database, hibernate, join, hql

I'm having some issues with HQL since I'm a newbie with it. Even though I don't have issues with "simple queries", I am currently stuck with a query involving three tables.

I have already gone through some tutorials, but I haven't been able to find a valid example for my needs. I have tried my best to explain my problem:

I have three different tables, let's name them `HOUSES`, `OWNERS`, and `OWNERINFOS`.

Given a `townId`, I need to **list all houses** from that town, **including** `name` and `surname` of that house-owner.

I made a really simple graph to show the connections between tables:

[image]

I'm also not sure which join-strategy I should use. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated, since solving this is a priority for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, post the relevant mappings and your attempts to solve the issue.

Comment: `Owner` associated to `OwnerInfo` as one-to-one or as one-to-many?

Comment: It's a one-to-one association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a template

```
class House {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_town")
    private Town town;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house")
    private List<Owner> owners;

}

class Owner {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_house")
    private House house;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_owner_info")
    private OwnerInfo ownerInfo;

}

class OwnerInfo {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "ownerInfo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Owner owner;

}
```

The simplest case with fetch all owners with owner info

```
from House h inner join fetch h.owners where h.town.id = :townId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will test this.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri You are welcome. `join fetch` can be slow, so you can improve the HQL request with an additional join and projections.